# Tripwire taking forever to accept report (Tripwire not accepting report)

Tags: tripwire

I have a problem

It's been a while since I ran Tripwire. (One Year)

I'm able to make a report. (Takes about 1h30)

But when I run the command to accept the file, it just runs and runs and runs, never asks me for the local passphrase. (It ran for three days now)

```
 sudo /usr/local/sbin/tripwire --update --accept-all --twrfile /usr/local/lib/tripwire/report/Filenameremoved-20140811-164856.twr
```

I had to cancel it because it took our site online.

How can I find out why it's doing this, and how to fix it?

### Update

I found the --verbose tag so now I can see it's output

It doesn't seem to be doing nothing now. Lets wait and see if it hangs.

### Update #2

24Hrs later. Now that I have the verbose I can see what's going on. It's stopped outputting information. The last entries only say

```
 Database update: Removing record xyz
```

The CPU allocated to it is 2.7% instead of 90%. It doesn't visually seem to be doing anything. :(

### Update #3

It's still running... One week later... X_x

Comment: May I have feedback on the downvote?

Comment: Crap downvote, I think. You just answered your own question, but you can't actually mark it as an answer because of the site's time limit on when you can do that.

Comment: @MikeyT.K. The tripwire isn't accepting the report yet a full 24 hours later even though it's verbose

Comment: Depending on your needs, perhaps AIDE would work out better for you (it works faster than tripwire for some).